# setLastModified - Java

Tags: java, synchronization, client-server, simpledateformat

Sorry in advance for spelling errors

**

- Introduction to the project

**
I need to create a system in Java which synchronyzes a single text file in all the comuters in the system .
In order to do it Ive created a server / Client to each computer, which links to all of his neighbors and checks who is the most uptadet file by using *lastModified* method.

- **The Problem**

A "probelm" that accured is when I get the file from my neighbor and update it, my *lastModified* is now bigger and thus he requsts the file from me- and so on a never ending loop, I've been suggested to solve it with *setLastModified* (I'm changing the *lastModified* time of my neighbor to mine) BUT it doesnt work ?!

I serched google and it says *setLastModified* sets modification times to the nearest second-  is this the problem?
how can I fix it / is their a method with more accuracy to set modification times?

```
 if (neighborLastMod  > file.lastModified()){
 getFileFromNeighbor(neighbor.getip(),neighbor.getport(),neighborLastMod);
 ....
 file.setLastModified(neighborLastMod);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last modified time stamp is precise only up to one second anyway, so accuracy is not the problem.

A possible problem is that while you are getting the file from the neighbor the last modified time stamp is temporarily set to the current time. To fix this your `getFileFromNeighbor` should save the file from the neighbor to a temporary file, set the last modified time stamp of the temporary file, and then do an atomic move or rename so that no system at any point sees a file with a higher time stamp.